# What is causing my code to have 1004 runtime error

Tags: excel, vba

I know this code is a mess but it's been at least working with no errors for weeks. The directories of all the files in question exist.

```
'''
Sub NEW_PO()

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Declare Variables''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim disc As String
Dim New_Data_Column As Long 'last date ordered column (number)
Dim NewPO_num As String 'New_Data_Column - 10 (needs leading "0" for single digits)
Dim Job_Num As String '= C2
Dim Cost_Code As String '= Active sheet name
Dim lastCol As String 'last date ordered column (Letter)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long 'last row of description column

Set sht = ActiveSheet

''''''''''''''''''''''Find last row and column(letter)''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
New_Data_Column = Cells(8, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastCol = Split(Columns(Range("A8").End(xlToRight).Column).Address(, False), ":")(1)
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Check for Data'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(lastCol & "11:" & lastCol & lastRow)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error! Please enter data to continue."
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(lastCol & "10")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error! Please enter date to continue."
        Range(lastCol & "10").Select
        Exit Sub
    Else
    
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Propmt for description of PO''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
disc = InputBox("Please enter a description for this Purchase Order.", "New Purchase Order")
If disc = "" Then
MsgBox "You Must Enter A Description!"
Exit Sub
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Set Cost Code''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Cost_Code = sht.name

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Set Job Number''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Job_Num = sht.Cells(2, 4).Text 'as text to keep formatting

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Set New Purchase Order Number'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    sht.Range("A4").Value = sht.Range("A4").Value + 1
    If sht.Range("A4").Value < 10 Then
    NewPO_num = "0" & sht.Range("A4").Value
Else
    NewPO_num = sht.Range("A4").Value
End If

''''''''''''Open PO Template and save as PO number & Copy PO to S/R Log''''''''''''''''''''
Dim sPath As String
sPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.path
Dim i As Integer
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastPO_row As Long
Dim lastSR_row As Long
Dim wkb3 As Workbook
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim sht4 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\1 CONSTRUCTION\Purchase Orders\Purchase Order Template.xlsm")
Set wkb3 = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\1 CONSTRUCTION\RECEIVED MATERIALS\SR Log.xlsx")

Set sht1 = wkb1.Sheets(Cost_Code)
Set sht2 = wkb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht3 = wkb3.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht4 = wkb2.Sheets("Job Addresses")
'''
```

This is where the error is occurring. Normally it would save the template as specified with no problems. I have deleted the code and written it in notepad and pasted it back into excel and it still gives an error. I've tried on multiple computers with the same result. I even uninstalled and reinstalled office and still not working.

```
'''
wkb2.SaveAs (sPath & "\1 CONSTRUCTION\Purchase Orders\" & Cost_Code & "\" & Job_Num & "-" & NewPO_num 
   & "-" & Cost_Code & " " & disc & ".xlsm")
wkb3.SaveAs (sPath & "\1 CONSTRUCTION\RECEIVED MATERIALS\" & Cost_Code & "\" & Job_Num & "-" & 
   NewPO_num & "-" & Cost_Code & " " & disc & ".xlsx")

sht2.name = Job_Num & "-" & NewPO_num & "-" & Cost_Code & " " & disc

lastPO_row = sht2.Cells(sht.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastSR_row = sht3.Cells(sht.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

''''''''''''Copy relevant entries to PO sheet and Shipping/Receiving Log'''''''''''''''''''

For i = 11 To lastRow
    If sht1.Cells(i, New_Data_Column).Value <> "" Then

        sht1.Range(lastCol & i).Copy
        sht2.Range("A" & lastPO_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range("D" & lastSR_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        sht1.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Copy
        sht2.Range("B" & lastPO_row & ":C" & lastPO_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht3.Range("A" & lastSR_row & ":B" & lastSR_row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        lastPO_row = lastPO_row + 1
        lastSR_row = lastSR_row + 1
    End If
Next

sht2.Range("E6").Value = wkb1.Sheets("PM Dashboard").Range("O3").Value
sht2.Range("E7").Value = Job_Num & "-" & NewPO_num & "-" & Cost_Code
sht2.Range("E8").Value = Dashboard.Sheets("PM Dashboard").Range("Y2").Value

'add this job's address to list of addresses on PO
sht4.Range("A7").Value = wkb1.Sheets("PM Dashboard").Range("O3").Value & vbNewLine _
& wkb1.Sheets("PM Dashboard").Range("AP3").Value & vbNewLine & wkb1.Sheets("PM 
Dashboard").Range("AP4").Value

wkb2.Save
sht3.Range("C1").Value = Job_Num & "-" & NewPO_num & "-" & Cost_Code & " " & disc
wkb3.Save
wkb3.Close

'''''''''''''''''''''copy over last column and hide previous'''''''''''''''''''''
sht1.Columns(New_Data_Column).Copy
sht1.Columns(New_Data_Column + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
sht1.Range(lastCol & "8:" & lastCol & "9").Copy
sht1.Range(lastCol & "8:" & lastCol & "9").Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Call HIDE
wkb1.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
End Sub
'''
```

Comment: If you step through with F8 what line is actually giving the error?

Comment: the one beginning with wkb2.SaveAs

Comment: I'm not sure but have you checked all your variables are holding the correct information? Also how long is the total path? Try setting your save path to a variable and viewing it. You may be exceeding the limit as it looks like it will be quite long depending on all the variables sizes.

Comment: If *it's been at least working with no errors for weeks*, then you changed something that made it stop working. It doesn't magically develop a new problem on its own. What did you change that broke it? Did you make a backup before that change in case it didn't work (by saving a copy of the file)? If so, did you compare the two versions to see what the differences between them are? There's too much noise and clutter in the code you posted to try to figure out the issue. This is in desperate need of a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: To make explicit what Simon has said, right before wkb2.SaveAs, insert two lines -- 1) wkb2FN = sPath & "\1 CONSTRUCTION\Purchase Orders\" & Cost_Code & "\" & Job_Num & "-" & NewPO_num 
   & "-" & Cost_Code & " " & disc & ".xlsm"  and  2)debug.print wkb2FN

Comment: also when I try to close the PO Template, after the code has opened it, the VBA editor gives me a "cannot find project or library" error

Comment: debug.print = D:\01 Job Template\1 CONSTRUCTION\Purchase Orders\203\000-03-203 test.xlsm

Comment: so the data being copied lives on sht1 in the range A11:I & lastRow. my boss wanted to  see if we could insert rows under say row 13, to  add some extra line items that would go along with the item on row 13. inserted the rows and then the error started. But, I have since deleted the sheet  and rebuilt it to how it was when the code was working.

Comment: when I comment out the wkb2.SaveAs line of code and run it, I get a run time '424' object required error at this line: sht2.Range("E8").Value = Dashboard.Sheets("PM Dashboard").Range("Y2").Value

Comment: sht2 value is empty when I hover over it on that line